# Escaping an apostrophe with xargs?

Tags: macos, shell, xargs

I'm trying to run a command on a bunch of files:

```
find . -name "*.ext" | xargs -0 cmd
```

The above works but it hangs because one of the folders stupidly has an ' in the file name (others have parens and other nonsense).

How do I safely send escaped output to my command?  e.g.:

```
cmd foo\ bar\(baz\)\'\!
```

[edit] I know I can run `find ... -exec cmd {} \;` but the actual command I'm running is more complicated and being piped through `sed` first

Comment: @anubhava - I specifically said I can't do that ;)

Comment: @anubhava - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU `find` you can use the `-print0` option

```
find -name "*.ext" -print0 | xargs -0 cmd
```

Otherwise you would have to ditch `xargs`. If you have Bash you could use

```
find -name "*.ext" | while read -a list ; do cmd "${list[@]}" ; done
```

Note that you do not have to specify current directory as the starting point. If no starting is specified, `.` is assumed.

Comment: `-print0` just lists one huge string of every file (OSX).  And on the 2nd I get `read: bad option: -a`

Comment: @MarkKahn `-a` is an option recognized by the bash builtin `read`. I can only assume you are using a different shell.

Comment: @MarkKahn `-print0` prints a list of NUL separated filenames, and `xargs -0` expects that, so it's not some incorrect or unexpected behaviour you're observing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `while` loop to process results of `find` command that uses `NUL` terminator using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   # echo "$file"
   cmd
done < <(find -iname "*.ext" -print0)
```

This can handle filenames with all kind of whitespaces, glob characters, newlines or any other special characters.

Note that this requires `bash` as process substitution is not supported in bourne shell.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel was born exactly because of `xargs` way of dealing with ", ' and space:

```
find . -name "*.ext" | parallel cmd
```